# Prove that $\langle x,y\rangle=x A y^*$ is an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

In $\mathbb{C}^2$, I want to show that $\langle x,y \rangle =xAy^*$ is an inner product space. I almost done with other properties of inner product but left only one property: $\langle x,x \rangle >0$ if $x \neq 0$.

To prove this,
$$\begin{align*}
\langle x,x \rangle&=(x_1, x_2)A(x_1, x_2)^*\\
&=\|x_1 \|^2-ix_2\overline{x_1}+ix_1\overline{x_2}+\|x_2 \|^2\\
&=\|x_1 \|^2 +2\operatorname{Re}(ix_1\overline{x_2})+\|x_2 \|^2
\end{align*}$$ 
where $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ is the real part of the complex number $z$.

I can't follow the last equality. Why does $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ appear here?

Comment: You can [see here how I have edited your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/aa5ade20-9908-4ce8-af86-2adeb3e23d03/view-source).

Comment: What's $A$ and why does it disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any complex number $w$, we know that $w + \bar w = 2 \Re(w)$.

Apply this with $w = ix_1\bar x_2$.